# cdh4.3，Exception from the logs ,after ./start-dfs.sh ,datanode and namenode start fail

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

here is the logs from hadoop-datanode-...log:

**FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for block pool Block pool BP-1421227885-192.168.2.14-1371135284949 (storage id DS-30209445-192.168.2.41-50010-1371109358645) service to /192.168.2.8:8020
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException): Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, storageID=DS-30209445-192.168.2.41-50010-1371109358645, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-40;cid=CID-f16e4a3e-4776-4893-9f43-b04d8dc651c9;nsid=1710848135;c=0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:3498)**

my mistake:namenode can start,datanode can't start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a Name Resolution issue.

> Datanode denied communication with namenode:
>   DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0,
>   storageID=DS-30209445-192.168.2.41-50010-1371109358645,
>   infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020,

Here DataNode is identifying itself as `0.0.0.0`.

Looks like dfs.hosts enforcement. Can you recheck on your NameNode's hdfs-site.xml configs that you are surely not using a dfs.hosts file?

This error may arise if the datanode that is trying to connect to the namenode is either listed in the file defined by dfs.hosts.exclude or that dfs.hosts is used and that datanode is not listed within that file. Make sure the datanode is not listed in excludes, and if you are using dfs.hosts, add it to the includes. Restart hadoop after that and run hadoop `dfsadmin -refreshNodes.`

HTH

Comment: Do you know of any other causes of this issue?  I've run into the same problem running hadoop-2.0.4-alpha, but not using dfs.hosts or dfs.hosts.exclude files.

Comment: Have you added the hostname and IP into the /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Adding the datanode hostnames into the namenode's /etc/hosts file fixed this for me.  For future reference, here's a shell command that I used to automatically add the slaves' hostnames: cat slaves | xargs -n1 -I {} bash -c "echo \`nslookup {} | grep Add | grep -v '#' | cut -f 2 -d ' '\` {}" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

Comment: Hi, @Tariq, I'm running Hadoop-2.1.0-beta, this error occurred. But I don't have root access in the machines, /etc/hosts is not allowed for me to edit. The machines can 'ping' and 'ssh' with each other. Can I have some other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: @Tariq Thanks, here is the complete logs of my datanode: https://gist.github.com/zfz/6373502.

Answer (score 9):

I saw this once too, the namenode server needs to do a reverse lookup request , 
so an nslookup 192.168.2.41 should return a name, it doesn't so 0.0.0.0 is also recorded

You don't need to hardcode address into /etc/hosts if you have dns working correctly (i.e. the in-addr.arpa file matches the entries in domain file) But if you don't have dns then you need to help hadoop out.

Comment: Don't understand why this got down voted. It fixed what was wrong with a test hadoop cluster I was setting up. Thanks @osscalvin. (The log error messages gave no indication that the namenode was trying to do a reverse dns)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse DNS lookup is required when a datanode tries to register with a namenode. I got the same exceptions with Hadoop 2.6.0 because my DNS does not allow reverse lookup.

But you can disable Hadoop's reverse lookup by setting this configuration "dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check" to false in hdfs-site.xml

I got this solution from [here](http://rrati.github.io/blog/2014/05/07/apache-hadoop-plus-docker-plus-fedora-running-images/) and it solved my problem.